# Why does Magento's translations fail after an unsuccessful payment transaction?

Tags: magento, translation, payment

we are using magento with onestepcheckout module in our shopping system. But when the payment process fails and when we get an error about payment, not all but some translations fails on the checkout page.

Has anybody face this problem before. I will be very happy if there is an solution.

P.S. I can solve the situation by hard-coding the translations. But I dont want to use this method.

Thank you

Comment: hy , write to support@onestepcheckout.com and they will answer this for you. Make sure you put your site url along so they can test and verify the behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a module developer creates a module, it's up to them to make sure that each and every phrase that could be translated is marked for translation. In Magento this means

1. Strings in template files are passed through the `->__` method
2. Labels, parameters, and other strings in XML fiels are marked with `translate` attribute

As an individual developer, if you're not developing applications/modules intended for translation it's easy to fall into the habit of not doing the above.  Also, the areas of Magento's XML configuration system that can (vs. can't) be translated aren't well documented.  It's easy to miss a string or two, and localization (along with everything else) is almost **never** tested.

All of which is a long way of saying, contact your vendor and file a bug.  If you want to play capitalism, since you've already hard-coded the translations, fix the core problem yourself and offer to sell the solution back to the onepage people.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem by upgrading the magento version to 1.5.0.1. In such cases, again I learned that the best thing is to upgrade to stable version.